# git merge: is there a way to force --squash?

Tags: git, merge, squash

So, the dev workflow for our project is like this: we create a task/bug ticket, and we branch off master to work on the task/bug, and eventually merge it back to master. We would like the commits on master to have nice messages. People committing on the task branch may not have good commit messages, and that's ok, but if the branch is to be merged, these commits with unclean messages are going into master.

One way to solve this is to always merge to master with --squash. That way, you get a chance to supply good commit message and treat the whole range of commits as one. I'm wondering if there's a way to *enforce* that? meaning, if we can let git server reject merges that aren't squashed?

Comment: if you have the bad branch on server, you can in `post-receive` check it have anything from the bad branch.

Comment: How does squash enforce 'good' commit messages?

Comment: No it doesn't, but it gives you a chance to write clean message. As I said, on feature/task branches, people can do interim commits as they want, but when they merge, I'd like to have good messages, and normal merge doesn't do that.

Answer (score 9):

While it's not directly forcing, you could set `--squash` as default merge option for the `master` branch:

```
git config branch.master.mergeoptions  "--squash"
```

This will always squash the commits being merged into master without having to specify the `--squash` option.

Comment: How would you undo this change?

Comment: @KamranKhan as long as you don't actively delete the merged branch, it's still present in your repo. Revert the merged commit with `git revert` and then proceed as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You need is a server side hook to ensure that what is getting pushed is what you need. You would reject any reference change that would introduce more than one non-merge commit. You could do other checks there like seeing that the comment contains a ticket number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rebase -i` on your branch, which would allow you to essentially squash all the commits on the branch into 1 commit, then merge that branch (1 commit) to master.

Comment: Indeed, but it sounds like you care more about what the master branch looks like than what the feature branch looks like. Sounds to me like some user education is in order: "Before you push to the server, rebase -i and write one nice commit message." :-)